# How many entries in the nth row of pascal triangle are divisible by 4(by even number)?

Tags: number-theory

Here, I tried to find any general formula for the question above. I did find the number of even entries in the nth row using this formula: $$[(n+1) - 2^{B(n)}]$$ where $B(n)$ is the sum of the bits in the binary representation of $n$.

From that formula, can I find the number of entries in the nth row divisible by 4??

Comment: This is [OEIS sequence A249732](https://oeis.org/A249732).  No formula is given there, just the (possibly optimistic) comment "This should have a formula (see [A048967](https://oeis.org/A048967))."

Comment: By Kummer's theorem, you want the number of $k$ such that the base-$2$ addition of $k$ and $n-k$ has at least two carries.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but a hint.
Let $n=\overline{a_r\dots a_0}$, $k=\overline{b_r\dots b_0}$ and $n-k=\overline{c_r\dots c_0}$. Let $f(n;p)$ be the largest number $k$ such that  $p^k|n!$ for a prime $p$. This is given by:
$$
f(n,p)=n-\sum_{i=0}^r a_i.
$$
Therefore the power of $p$ in $\binom nk$ is given by:
$$
g(n,k,p)=\sum_{i=0}^r b_i+\sum_{i=0}^r c_i-\sum_{i=0}^r a_i.
$$
You can argue yourself that this power is equal to the number of carries when $k$ and $n-k$ are added and this is [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem). The only problem is counting $k$ with two carries in their sum which seems to be not clear to me now.

---

[Luca's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem) can shed a light on the number of even entries in the row $n$. The first conclusion can be that when $n=\overline{1\dots 1}=2^k-1$ for some $k$, all the entries are odd. Or when $n$ is a power of $2$, $n-2$ entries are even.

Answer (score 0):

If this can help, the $\bmod4$ Pascal's triangle. (Gray, blue, red, yellow.) It features some form of autosimilarity.

[image]